# How to create different types of fields using Metadata?

Tags: apex, metadata-api, metadata

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

MetadataService.CustomField customField = new MetadataService.CustomField();
customField.fullName = 'Test__c.TestField__c';
customField.label = 'Test Field';
customField.type_x = 'Checkbox';
 MetadataService.AsyncResult[] results =
service.create(new List<MetadataService.Metadata> { customField });
```

I am trying to create fields with the above code but I am getting `Invalid type: MetadataService.MetadataPort` Error. Can we create different types of fields using metadata? if so what is the issue with the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can create Checkbox field using MetadataService however in your case it seems like you don't have the MetadataService class in your org where you are running the code. Code sample you are trying to use is part of [apex-mdapi](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) wrapper.

Below code works fine after having the necessary library in the org. This code creates a checkbox field on Account object.

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

MetadataService.CustomField customField = new MetadataService.CustomField();
customField.fullName = 'Account.TestField__c';
customField.label = 'Test Field';
customField.type_x = 'Checkbox';
customField.defaultValue = 'false';
List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results = service.createMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata[] { customField });
```